# jquery mobile: drop down options populated through javascript is not being shown as a selectable drop-down its plainly rendering.PFA

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

this is how its rendering.
[image]here is what i used

this is how i need

[image]

on document ready im calling populate function and passing class name 'fromTime' to it.its just rendering it plainly not the options in the select box.

```
function populate(selector) {
    var select = $(selector);
    var selectBox = $("<select></select>");
    var hours, minutes, ampm ;
    for(var k = 700; k <= 2300; k += 100){
        var i=0;
        for(var j=0;j<=45;j+=15){
            i=k+j
            hours = Math.floor(i / 100);
            minutes = i % 100;

            if(minutes>10){
                minutes=minutes+"";
            }else{
                minutes=0+""+minutes;
            }
            ampm = hours % 24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
            hours = hours % 12;
            if (hours === 0){
                hours = 12;
            }
            var valueString=hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
            select.append($('<option></option>')
                    .attr('value', i)
                    .text(valueString));

        }
    }

}
```

here is html code

```
<div class="ui-field-contain">
                           <label for="select-custom-20">Long list:</label>
                            <select name="select-custom-20" class="fromTime" id="select-custom-20" data-native-menu="false">
                               <option value=''>Start Time</option> 
                                                                                    </select>
                        </div>
```

Comment: its not a duplicate @omar but given answer worked for me.

Comment: given answer and dupe answer are the same, don't you think?

Comment: then answer should be duplicate not question, u must also think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand your question, if your want to refresh your select box :

```
$('#select-custom-20').selectmenu("refresh");
```

Comment: updated with screen shots

Comment: You need to pass the selector `#select-custom-20` instead of `.fromTime`,

Comment: `populate("#select-custom-20");`
then
`$('#select-custom-20').selectmenu("refresh");`

Answer (score -1):

Did you called the method. I think no, you did created a method that append time options into the select tag but not called it. So, You have to call this method some where / at some event

I am adding an example that load the dropdown at click event on an anchor tag.

[Example is given Here](http://jsfiddle.net/y1uxfkug/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#trigger').click(function(){
   populate('#select-custom-20');

    });
function populate(selector) {
    var select = $(selector);
    var selectBox = $("<select></select>");
    var hours, minutes, ampm ;
    for(var k = 700; k <= 2300; k += 100){
        var i=0;
        for(var j=0;j<=45;j+=15){
            i=k+j
            hours = Math.floor(i / 100);
            minutes = i % 100;

            if(minutes>10){
                minutes=minutes+"";
            }else{
                minutes=0+""+minutes;
            }
            ampm = hours % 24 < 12 ? 'AM' : 'PM';
            hours = hours % 12;
            if (hours === 0){
                hours = 12;
            }
            var valueString=hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
            select.append($('<option></option>')
                    .attr('value', i)
                    .text(valueString));

        }
    }

}
});
```

Hope it helps.....